# Launch configured cmd from Python

Tags: python, windows, process, exec

I'm on **Windows**. I am trying to write a Python 2.x script (let's call it `setup.py`) which would enable the following scenario:

1. User runs cmd to open a console window
2. In that console window, user runs `setup.py`
3. User finds themselves in the same console window, but now the cmd running there has had its environment (env. variables) modified by `setup.py`

`setup.py` modifies the environment by adding a new environment variable `FOO` with value `foo`, and by preneding something to `PATH`.

On Linux, I would simply use `os.exec*e` to replace the Python process with a shell with the environment configured.

I tried the same approach on Windows (like `os.exec*e(os.environ['ComSpec'])`), but it doesn't work, the environment of the newly executed cmd is messed up like this:

- Running just `set` doesn't list `FOO` and doesn't show the effect on `PATH`. Running `set FOO`, however, shows `FOO=foo`, and `echo %FOO%` echoes `foo`.
- Running `set PATH` or `echo %PATH%` shows the modified `PATH` variable. Running `set path` or `echo %path%` shows the value *without* the modification (even though env. vars are normally case insensitive on Windows).
- If I type `exit`, the conole remains hanging in some state not accepting input, until I hit `Ctrl+C`. After that, it apparently returns to the `cmd` which originally called `setup.py`.

So clearly, `os.exec*e` doesn't work for this scenario on Windows. Is there a different way to achieve what I want? Is there a combination of `subprocess.Popen()` flags which would enable me to exit the calling Python process and leave the called cmd runnig, ideally in the same console? Or would accessing `CreateProcess` through `ctypes` help?

If necessary, I would settle for launching a new console window and closing the old one, but I certainly can't afford having the old console window hang in frozen state, waiting for a newly created one to close.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much simpler solution if it's acceptable to use a Windows batch file in addition to your script, since the batch file runs in the calling process, and can therefore modify its environment.

Given a file `setup.bat`, which looks like this...

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('python setup.py') do %%a
```

...and a file `setup.py` which looks like this...

```
import os
print 'set FOO=foo'
print 'set PATH=%s;%s' % ('C:\\my_path_dir', os.environ['PATH'])
```

...and assuming `python.exe` in in the PATH, then calling `setup.bat` from the command line will set the environment variables in the calling process, while still allowing you to make the `setup.py` script as complicated as you like, as long as it prints the commands you want to execute to stdout.

**Update based on comments**

If your `setup.py` has multiple modes of operation, you could make the `setup.bat` a generic wrapper for it. Suppose instead `setup.bat` looks like this...

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "setenv" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('python setup.py %1') do %%a
) else (
    python setup.py %*
)
```

...and `setup.py` looks like this...

```
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'setenv':
    print 'set FOO=foo'
    print 'set PATH=%s;%s' % ('C:\\my_path_dir', os.environ['PATH'])
else:
    print "I'm gonna do something else with argv=%r" % sys.argv
```

...would that not suffice?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was actually considering falling back to something like this if I don't find a more direct way. The problem with this is that my real `setup.py` actually has several modes of operation (based on commandline arguments), only one of which is what I described in the question.

Comment: Updated answer. My batch file programming skills are pretty limited, so it might not be 100% correct, but it seems to work.